# Excel VBA Data Validation List Error '1004'

Tags: excel, vba, list, validation

I have created a spreadsheet that automatically populates ink item and description cells based on an inputted part number. It pulls these from a separate worksheet. I want to make a change so that after these numbers are pulled, the user has the option to rearrange if needed. The problem is that I don't want them to be able to type any number they want to reduce the chance of errors.

I have tried adding VBA code to create a drop-down list using the numbers that were pulled previously but keep getting an application-defined or object-defined error when it gets into the `.Add` portion of the data validation code.

I have renamed the cells containing the item numbers to "part_list" and currently have the code portion below to try to add data validation to just one deck:

[image: RMS Sheet in Workbook]

```
ActiveSheet.Protect UserInterFaceOnly:=True

Dim Validlist As String
Validlist = "part_list"

Sheets("RMS").Range("C11:D11").Activate
With Range("C11:D11").Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
    Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=Validlist"
    'CODE ABOVE IS GIVING ERROR 1004***************************
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
```

Comment: Try `Formula1:="=" & Validlist` instead of `Formula1:="=Validlist"`. Validlist is a variable - therefore you have to concatenate it. Or use `Formula1:="=part_list"`

Comment: Unfortunately both of these give the same error. I saw other posts saying my list needed to be defined as a string which is how I got to the above code

Comment: Try removing `Operator:=xlBetween,`

Comment: Same error. I also tried both iterations of the fromula1 format you shared

Comment: then propably sth is wrong with your list. Try recording a macro when applying the validation list manually.

Comment: Recording the macro changes it to Formula1:="=$P$18:$P$27", but Excel still doesn't seem to like that format either :(

Comment: Then sth is wrong with that range.

Comment: I believe the issue was in the protection of the worksheet. After I added Sheets("RMS").Unprotect at the beginning and Sheets("RMS").Protect at the end of the Macro it started working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From reading your question and trying out your code the issue is you should be writing

```
Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=part_list"
```

not

```
Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=Validlist"
```

Your code worked for me provided the range name is correct.

Comment: It still isn't working on my end. Could it be that I am working with a merged cell to add the data validation to?

Comment: Try also removing the  ActiveSheet.Protect UserInterFaceOnly:=True at the top.

Comment: I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Just to confirm you commented out or removed the sheet protection, you made sure the sheet is unprotected, and that the range name for you dropdown list is correct?

Comment: Yes. It works if I manually unprotect the sheet, but I don't want the user to be able to do this since the format and information needs to be standardized

Comment: Right so you need to get the code to unprotect the sheet at the start, do what it needs to do, then protect the sheet again at the end.

Comment: That works! Thank you so much for your help. I sincerely appreciate it since I am no VBA whiz